# Why do I get a numberformatexception when I try to parse this specific string to an int?

Tags: java, parsing, int, token, numberformatexception

I was working on a project for my AP Computer Science class that allows the user to sort music, when I came across this error. When the line,
`"2008  50  Ashley Tisdale  He Said, She Said"` (each part is separated through a tab)
was input through an input file, my program failed to respond correctly and gave me these errors

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Song.parse(Song.java:19)
    at GazillionSongs.main(GazillionSongs.java:44)
```

After seeing this I have concluded that my error came from this code.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

         while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);  
         }

         ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

         Scanner allCommands = new Scanner(command);

         for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            int year = 0;
            int rank = 0;
            String artist = "";
            String title = "";
            Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
            song.parse(lines.get(i));
            songs.add(song);
         }
```

and this one, from my Song class.

```
public Song(int year, int rank, String artist, String title) {
      this.year = year;
      this.rank = rank;
      this.artist = artist;
      this.title = title;
   }

public static Song parse(String s) {
      String[] tokens = s.split("/t");
      year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
      rank = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
      artist = tokens[2];
      title = tokens[3];
      Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
      return song;
   }
```

I apologize if this is not enough information to go on, as I am new to this site.

Can someone explain why I am getting these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most obvious thing I see is, that tabulator is \t, not /t. The following code works as expected:

```
String s = "2008    50  Ashley  Tisdale He  Said,   She Said";
String[] tokens = s.split("\t");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) says

> `public class NumberFormatException extends IllegalArgumentException`
>
> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

Since  `String[] tokens = s.split("/t");` line will not split tabular as `\t` is tabular not `/t` hence String didn't get split and you get `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your regex.
Use below regex in split api,It will split based on spaces in between strings.

> str.split("\s+")